# Scala equivalent of Haskell's insertWith for Maps

Tags: scala, dictionary

I'm looking to do the simple task of counting words in a String. The easiest way I've found is to use a Map to keep track of word frequencies. Previously with Haskell, I used its `Map`'s function `insertWith`, which takes a function that resolves key collisions, along with the key and value pair. I can't find anything similar in Scala's library though; only an add function (`+`), which presumably overwrites the previous value when re-inserting a key. For my purposes though, instead of overwriting the previous value, I want to add 1 to it to increase its count.

Obviously I could write a function to check if a key already exists, fetch its value, add 1 to it, and re-insert it, but it seems odd that a function like this isn't included. Am I missing something? What would be the Scala way of doing this?

Comment: Another way of doing it in Scala would be to split the string at whitespaces, group by identity, map the second element of the resulting tuples to their size, and you have a histogram, without the need of mutating anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a map with default value and then update with `+=`

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val count = mutable.Map[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
count("abc") += 1
println(count("abc"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string then why not use the split module

```
import Data.List.Split

let mywords = "he is a good good boy"
length $ nub $ splitOn " " mywords
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with Scala's immutable style, you could create your own class with immutable semantics:

```
class CountMap protected(val counts: Map[String, Int]){
    def +(str: String) = new CountMap(counts + (str -> (counts(str) + 1)))
    def apply(str: String) = counts(str)
}

object CountMap {
    def apply(counts: Map[String, Int] = Map[String, Int]()) = new CountMap(counts.withDefaultValue(0))
}
```

And then you can use it:

```
val added = CountMap() + "hello" + "hello" + "world" + "foo" + "bar"
added("hello")
>>2
added("qux")
>>0
```

You might also add `apply` overloads on the companion object so that you can directly input a sequence of words, or even a sentence:

```
object CountMap {
    def apply(counts: Map[String, Int] = Map[String, Int]()): CountMap = new CountMap(counts.withDefaultValue(0))
    def apply(words: Seq[String]): CountMap = CountMap(words.groupBy(w => w).map { case(word, group) => word -> group.length })
    def apply(sentence: String): CountMap = CountMap(sentence.split(" "))
}
```

And then the you can even more easily:

```
CountMap(Seq("hello", "hello", "world", "world", "foo", "bar"))
```

Or:

```
CountMap("hello hello world world foo bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [updatedWith](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/collection/immutable/MapOps.html#updatedWith-3bd):

```
counters.updatedWith(key):
  case Some(old) => Some(old + new)
  case _ => Some(new)
```